# I get this error using PyTorch: RuntimeError: gather_out_cpu(): Expected dtype int64 for index

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an AI with PyTorch, but I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: gather_out_cpu(): Expected dtype int64 for index
```

And this is my function:

```
def learn(self, batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action):
    outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    next_outputs = self.model(batch_next_state).detach().max(1)[0]
    target = self.gamma * next_outputs + batch_reward
    td_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(outputs, target)
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    td_loss.backward(retain_variables = True)
    self.optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the data type of your `batch_action` tensor before passing it to `torch.gather`.

```
def learn(...):
    batch_action = batch_action.type(torch.int64) 
    outputs = ...
    ...

# or
outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.type(torch.int64).unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me as well. But why did it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really late response (since it was 1 year 8 months ago that it was asked) but I came across a similar error with one of my implementations. I got the code from a course I am currently taking. The code is very much similar.
In my case, I found that when I called the learn function later on in the code, the arguments passed into parameters `batch_reward` and `batch_action` where swapped. This meant that the value for `batch_reward` pointed to `batch_action` and vice versa.

(below is from code in the question asked)

```
 def learn(self, batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action):
outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
next_outputs = self.model(batch_next_state).detach().max(1)[0]
```

(below is from my code)

```
 def learn(self, batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action):
    outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    next_outputs = self.model(batch_next_state).detach().max(1)[0]
    target = self.gamma*next_outputs + batch_reward
    td_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(outputs, target)
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    td_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
    self.optimizer.step()

def update(self, reward, new_signal):
    new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal).float().unsqueeze(0)
    self.memory.push((self.last_state, new_state, torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)]), torch.Tensor([self.last_reward])))
    action = self.select_action(new_state)
    if len(self.memory.memory) > 100:
        batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_action, batch_reward = self.memory.sample(100)
        self.learn(batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action)
    self.last_action = action
    self.last_state = new_state
    self.last_reward = reward
    self.reward_window.append(reward)
    if len(self.reward_window) > 1000:
        del self.reward_window[0]
    return action
```

When the learn function is called from within update function, `batch_reward` argument is passed to `batch_action` and vice versa. This in turn causes the above error that you and I got when executing the code. So I guess the solution to the error is somewhat of a simple typo where in wrong arguments passed into wrong parameters.
Bottom Line - the solution: check the code where arguments are passed into the function. There might be a mismatched argument and parameter.